# How to run a loop until an exception is not generated

Tags: java, exception, loops, throw

I hava a method called `test()` that throws an exception.

I want to write a loop that executes as long as it throws an exception, and breaks when it no longer throws an exception.

Can any one hint me on the logic that must be use?

For example I tried,

```
int i=0;
while(test())
{
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Maybe it's not a good idea to use exceptions for flow control

Comment: If possible, avoid this method, because running a loop until the exceptions are thrown is very unreliable and may result into unnecessary memory leaks

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's necessarily unreliable, because it really depends on the overall program behavior. But if you need to run this loop for awhile, and can afford to pause it for small increments, calling Thread.sleep(100) at an always-reachable point in the loop can save a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i=0;
while (true) {
    try {
        test();
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        i++; // Loop will continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the need for int i? The logic that the OP asked for will work fine without it.

Comment: I think he want to print `i` value after loop.